# MDI Show Exceptions

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this MainForm as my MDI Parent. When the time I called my MDIChild it usually appear once. The time I close my MDIChild and Open it again. It has an ObjectDisposedException was unhandled (Cannot access a disposed object.)

```
private void BtnUserPanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormAccounts fa = new FormAccounts();
    fa.MdiParent = this;
    fa.Show(); //ObjectDisposedException was unhandled
}
```

How would I trap this error in order that when I close my MDIForm and Open again it shows my MDIForm once again without this ObjectDisposedException.

I got this from my MDI Parent stack trace when I try to close the MDIChildren then open the MDChildren again:

> Unhanded exception: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name:
>   'FormAccounts'. at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle() at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle() at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle() at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.Show() at
>   System.Windows.Forms.COntrol.Show() at
>   Lendmattic.UI.FormMain.BtnUserPanel_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   in FormMain.cs:line71

Comment: [tag:winforms] is not needed.

Comment: for an idea from i lived : 

i changed my project to gain perf from offline to online db connection.. before this, i think on it and i discovered a better way.. so i deleted 2 of my class (and 2 winforms UI which have the controls of those classes) which are very long (117 properties for each class)

while i completely change my codes when i debug and / or close the app i got this disposed object error with that 2 class which i deleted.. the values on dataset but there was no class or control assigned with them

may you did something like this and forgot to correct / not complete your action ?